# Magento 2.3 prefix admin not displayed as dropdown

Tags: magento2.3, customer, magento2.3.5, prefix

We use the default customer Show Prefix method. This works fine on the frontend.

But in the admin panel, the prefix in the customer is displayed as a input open text field, not as a dropdown with the options displayed.

For some reason the prefix in the admin panel is not displayed well.

How can we solve this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to extends/customise the forms that are used in the backend to render the customer's forms.

for instance, customer_address_form.xml may be customised with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd" component="Magento_Customer/js/form/components/form">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="prefix" sortOrder="10" formElement="select">
            <formElements>
                <select>
                    <settings>
                        <options class="Mbs\PrefixBecomesSelect\Model\Config\PrefixOptions"/>
                    </settings>
                </select>
            </formElements>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and customer_form.xml customised with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="customer">
        <field name="prefix" formElement="select">
            <formElements>
                <select>
                    <settings>
                        <options class="Mbs\PrefixBecomesSelect\Model\Config\PrefixOptions"/>
                    </settings>
                </select>
            </formElements>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

the Model used in these customisation like below:

```
<?php

namespace Mbs\PrefixBecomesSelect\Model\Config;

class PrefixOptions implements \Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Options
     */
    private $options;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Options $options
    ) {
        $this->options = $options;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $rawOptions = $this->options->getNamePrefixOptions();

        $options[] = ['value' => '', 'label' => '-'];

        foreach ($rawOptions as $label => $value) {
            $options[] = ['value' => $value, 'label' => $label];
        }

        return $options;
    }
}
```